# Can I destroy my /test folder if i'm using Rspec and Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this possible?
Or would I miss something? (Fixtures,..?)

Because: When I use autotest with rspec, autotest doesnt seem to work? It loads, but nothing else happens, even if i change a file..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can remove the directory 'test' completely. if you use fixtures you can put them in spec/fixtures. thought fixtures are not a good idea imho :)

Comment: Because fixtures are just too hard to maintain. Use Stubs and Mocks instead! Complete Mocking Framework is already built in in RSpec.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but you have to use command

```
autospec
```

and not

```
autotest
```

if you use RSpec.